# Iterating a div with Thymeleaf + SpringMVC

Tags: java, loops, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to iterate a List with divs but it only repeat once. I think it's a html(thyemeleaf) code mistake, but I can't find it. I have another iteration working like that, but instead of div's it's using tr and td.

Maybe it doesn't work with div's?

**HTML Code**

```
                <div id="portfoliolist" th:each="produto : ${estoque}">
                    <div class="portfolio usado escambolivre" data-cat="usado escambolivre">
                        <div class="portfolio-wrapper"> 
                        <a rel="group" title=""  th:href="'/produto?id='+${produto.id}">
                            <img th:src="'images/'+${produto.id}+'.jpg'" alt=""  class="img-responsive caixa-img-produto" />
                        </a>
                            <div class="label">
                                <div class="label-text">
                                    <span class="text-category" th:text="${produto.nome}"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="label-bg"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Controller Code**

```
@Autowired
Estoque produtos;
@RequestMapping("/produtos")
    public String buscar(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("estoque", produtos.getProdutos());
        System.out.println(produtos.getProdutos());

        return "produtos";
    }
```

**Service Code**

```
@Service
public class Estoque {

    private static List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        produtos.add(new Produto(new BigInteger("1"), "Nike Shox", new BigDecimal("500.00"), "Modelo v3"));
        produtos.add(new Produto(new BigInteger("2"), "Conta de LoL", new BigDecimal("300.00"), "Platina 1"));
        produtos.add(new Produto(new BigInteger("3"), "Nintendo 3DS", new BigDecimal("660.00"), "Acompanha 4 jogos originais"));
        produtos.add(new Produto(new BigInteger("4"), "AWP Asiimov", new BigDecimal("130.00"), "Pouco usada (minimal wear)"));
    }

    public void addProduto(BigInteger id, String nome, BigDecimal preco, String descricao){
        produtos.add(new Produto(id, nome, preco, descricao));
    }

    public List<Produto> getProdutos(){
        return Estoque.produtos;
    }
}
```

[And this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/incqE.png)

[What it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljAit.png)

Comment: What does `System.out.println(produtos.getProdutos());` output?

Comment: Th:each works on div. Have you looked at the generated HTML code (view source in browser) to see if you have the four divs, or not ? It might also be a css issue, hiding the last 3 elements. Is your th:each at the right level ? Where it is placed you'll get several div#portfomiolist, while perhaps you rxpect one portfoliolist, and several div#portfolio ?

Comment: @Thierry thank you, I thought I couldn't be wrong with placement but I was and just double checked because of your comment.

Comment: Use th:href = "@{...}"  for specify URL , its the standard URL syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, I've found the answer.

The foreach was in the wrong div, should be in the one below it.

This code now works:

```
                <div id="portfoliolist" >
                    <div class="portfolio usado escambolivre" data-cat="usado escambolivre" th:each="produto : ${estoque}">
                        <div class="portfolio-wrapper"> 
                        <a rel="group" title=""  th:href="'/produto?id='+${produto.id}">
                            <img th:src="'images/'+${produto.id}+'.jpg'" alt=""  class="img-responsive caixa-img-produto" />
                        </a>
                            <div class="label">
                                <div class="label-text">
                                    <span class="text-category" th:text="${produto.nome}"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="label-bg"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```